# Headphone volume issue when using AvAudioEngine output

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-audio, avaudioengine

I am using AVAudioEngine to capture a user's voice while applying some real-time effects(like reverb or sth) to the voice.Here's my code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController{
var audioEngine:AVAudioEngine!
var audioReverb:AVAudioUnitReverb!
var audioInputNode:AVAudioInputNode!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)
    session.setActive(true, error: nil)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func recordWithReverb(sender: AnyObject) {


    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    audioEngine.stop()
    audioEngine.reset()



    audioInputNode = audioEngine.inputNode


    audioReverb = AVAudioUnitReverb()
    audioReverb.loadFactoryPreset(.LargeRoom)
    audioReverb.wetDryMix = 50


    audioEngine.attachNode(audioReverb)
    let inputFormat = audioReverb.inputFormatForBus(0)
    audioEngine.connect(audioInputNode, to: audioReverb, format: inputFormat)
    audioEngine.connect(audioReverb, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: inputFormat)


    audioEngine.startAndReturnError(nil)
}
   }
```

When I test it with headphones which have mic on it(like earpods), it all works well.But when I use some other headphones that is without mic (so I could only use the mic on the iphone as the input source), the right speaker of the headphone always sounds smaller than the left speaker of the headphone.How can I fix it?

And there's another question I'd like to ask, when I write the code

```
 var audioEngine:AVAudioEngine!
 var audioReverb:AVAudioUnitReverb!
 var audioInputNode:AVAudioInputNode!
```

inside the function "recordWithReverb",the code cannot work correctly, I can't get any output, Why did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like set the wetDryMix value bigger can solve this problem.

```
audioReverb.wetDryMix = 80
```